# How do I query a SQL database to return the first "page" containing the specified data?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, sqlite

```
------------------------
|      |     A   |     |
------------------------
|      |     B   |     |
------------------------
|      |     C   |     |
------------------------ -----Page 1
|      |     D   |     |
------------------------
|      |     E   |     |
------------------------
|      |     F   |     |
------------------------ -----Page 2
|      |     F   |     |
------------------------
|      |     F   |     |
------------------------
|      |     G   |     | -----Page 3
```

Please excuse my ascii art, never done it before.

I have a database with the second colunm sorted as shown above. The database displays to the user in "pages" of 3 rows each.

The user is then going to seach (via a text input) for some data from the sorted second column and wants the page returned that has the first occurance of that data.

For example, the user enters "F", page 2 is returned as it contains the first occurance of F in this sort order.

For example, the user enters "C", page 1 is returned as it contains the first (and only) occurance of C in this sort order.

What is the query to do this?

My first thought is to find the row of the first occurance, calculate what page it is in and then query that page as normal.   Is that the most efficient way, or is there some build in functionality.

Thank you.

-SQLite (via C++ API)
-Visual Studio 2003.NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your first thought was the correct one. This is because is it not very regular to have "hidden info" in your database, and base queries on that. Your *hidden info* here is on which page something is, which is merely based on which row it is if sorted by a certain column.

There are different ways to approach this, though. The most common one, I think, would be not to display page 2 when a user searches for F, but to display page 2.66 (which also has three items). It has some drawbacks, but it also has advantages over your method. Another way would be to add a column to the table which describes on which page something is. This has the disadvantage that as long as you are sticking to the "formula division" it is redundant data. It also is problematic if data is added to any other place than the "end" of the table. It does have the added flexibility that you can decide to give a certain page an extra item.

Comment: I agree. Why do you need to go to page 2? Just display a page with F starting at the top. If there are 5 Fs and I have the bad luck of the first one being the third in a page, I'll have to visit 3 pages to see them all, instead of just two as when the page starts with what I searched for.

Comment: @Emtucifor: however if we then want to go to the next page it won't be continuous based on the page starting at f....?

Comment: If I was writing a web page, my links to go to the next and previous page would not use a page number but an item number (to start the page). Thus you can use the current page top each time to decide the index of the next page, just by adding the # of items per page. A negative item number would just start at the first item.

Comment: @Emtucifor: That makes a whole lot of sense and is a fine implementation of what I meant when I described the _most common_ approach.

Comment: Also, don't get me wrong, I've used the page parameter thing before, but only when there was no need to jump to a particular position of a pre-existing pre-paged set of data. The moment jumping to a particular position becomes important, then I would abandon page number entirely and work entirely with item number + page size.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a database with the second
>   colunm sorted as shown above.

No, you don't.  SQL tables are unordered.  What you have is a `SELECT` result that *just happens* to be in `ROWID` order *as an implementation detail*.  If you want to base queries on the row number, then it should be an explicit column:

```
CREATE TABLE T(
    ID        INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    Letter    CHAR
);
```

Comment: @dan04: I should have explained more but the question was more for something else. I actually created a database view ORDER BY column 2.